# Adding custom type in Umbraco 8

Tags: c#, umbraco, umbraco8

I've been testing Umbraco 8 for a while, and i'm stuck on an attempt to add a custom workflow type to umbraco forms.

I tried the simple example from https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/Add-ons/UmbracoForms/Developer/Extending/Adding-a-Workflowtype, but my issue starts at the guide about registering this new type so it shows up in umbrack (https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/Add-ons/UmbracoForms/Developer/Extending/Adding-a-Type)

Part of the doc doesn't match the visual code project i'm working on:

```
Finally compile the project and copy the .dll to your website /bin folder or copy the .cs file to the app_code directory.
```

There's no app_code directory, however i found that if i put the file in /App_data/Models it'll try to compile it when i launch the umbraco project, but this fails as it can't find any of the using directives e.g. Umbraco.BusinessLogic or Umbraco.Forms.Core.

I haven't been able to find anyone with a similar problem. I tried creating a new Umbraco project using visual studio, installing Umbraco via Nuget, but the folder structure still doesn't match any documentation, keeping me at a loss for how to continue.

Does anyone know what i'm missing, and why my folder structure doesn't match any of the assumptions in our.umbraco.com guides and docs ?

Answer (score 0):

I've added a few workflows on a recent project in Umbraco 8. I created a new folder in the website root called UmbracoForms and within that created the custom workflow classes.

This class then inherits from WorkflowType and is automatically picked up by Umbraco.

e.g. public class SaveUsersContactDetailsToSession : WorkflowType {}

Just be mindful of setting the ID, Name, and Description. All Umbraco namespaces will be available and you'll be able to use Dependency Injection.